# Does Swift have any built-in reverse function for a Bool?

Tags: swift, boolean

The following extension works, yet I was wondering if Swift has any out of the box function that does such reverse. I already command clicked on Bool and it doesn't have anything reverse like nor I saw anything in the Documentation.

```
var x = true

extension Bool{
    mutating func reverse() -> Bool{
        if self == true {
            self = false
            return self
        } else {
          self = true
          return self
        }
    }
}

print(x.reverse()) // false
```

Comment: What about `x = !x`?

Comment: @MartinR Doesn't work well with optionals, e.g. in the context of optional chaining: `!a?.b ?? true` doesn't compile.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

`!` is the "logical not" operator:

```
var x = true
x = !x
print(x) // false
```

In Swift 3 this operator is defined as a static function of the `Bool` 
type:

```
public struct Bool {

    // ...

    /// Performs a logical NOT operation on a Boolean value.
    ///
    /// The logical NOT operator (`!`) inverts a Boolean value. If the value is
    /// `true`, the result of the operation is `false`; if the value is `false`,
    /// the result is `true`.
    ///
    ///     var printedMessage = false
    ///
    ///     if !printedMessage {
    ///         print("You look nice today!")
    ///         printedMessage = true
    ///     }
    ///     // Prints "You look nice today!"
    ///
    /// - Parameter a: The Boolean value to negate.
    prefix public static func !(a: Bool) -> Bool

   // ...
}
```

There is no built-in mutating method which negates a boolean,
but you can implement it using the `!` operator:

```
extension Bool {
    mutating func negate() {
        self = !self
    }
}

var x = true
x.negate()
print(x) // false
```

Note that in Swift, mutating methods usually do not *return* the new
value (compare `sort()` vs. `sorted()` for arrays).

---

**Update:** The proprosal

- [SE-0199 Adding `toggle` to `Bool`](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0199-bool-toggle.md)

has been accepted, and a future version of Swift will have a 
`toggle()` method in the standard library:

```
extension Bool {
  /// Equivalent to `someBool = !someBool`
  ///
  /// Useful when operating on long chains:
  ///
  ///    myVar.prop1.prop2.enabled.toggle()
  mutating func toggle() {
    self = !self
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit and pointing out to the `!` operator, it was informative. true, only that it's not mutating

Answer (score 23):

#### Swift 4.2 and above.

As pointed out by Martin previously, the toggle function has finally arrived

So now, you can simply write

```
bool.toggle()
```

and that would give you the intended results.

Answer (score 5):

**For above swift 4.2**

```
var isVisible = true
print(isVisible.toggle())  // false
```

**for else**

```
isVisible = !isVisible
```

Answer (score 3):

one of the best way and simpliest way to do this is to check 
the bool is equal to false as you set it like this:

```
 var mybool = true
 mybool = mybool == false
```

mybool will then always be the oposite of what it was before

Answer (score 0):

Before you made the edit, your function was equivalent to the trivial assignment `x = false;`

But the way you now have it can be simplified to `x = !x;`. (That is `true` maps to `false` and `false` maps to `true`.)

(Note that the cool cats in C might even use `x ^= 1`, to *toggle* the least significant bit.)

Comment: Oh the joys of the moving spec. A career in project management awaits the OP.

Comment: *to toggle the least significant bit* what does that mean?

Comment: Means to think of a number in its binary form, and change the last bit to a 0 if it's 1 and vice-versa.

Comment: `x ^= 1` does not compile in Swift if `x` is a `Bool`.

Comment: @Bathsheba I see now what you mean, it truly is the least significant bit to change, and thanks career advice :D

Comment: @MartinR: Absolutely. That's why it's really only a C-like thing to do (which only sort of has a boolean type).

Comment: Then I misunderstood your final remark and apologize.

Comment: @Honey: But don't take it! Aim to become the chief software architect. That's where the real fun is.

Comment: @Bathsheba Honestly that's what I'm aiming for, yet I'm new to the ocean of iOS and know nothing of backend. Only how to consume an API. Any guidance is appreciated :/

Comment: @Honey: I started with C, then C++, VBA, Excel, then Java. Good luck!

Comment: Personally, I'd suggest deleting the "cool cats" stuff. It's cute, but (a) you're likely to confuse readers not familiar with the idiosyncrasies of C; and (b) it's not even a terribly good pattern in C.